# CXF Failover issues

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, failover

I am attempting to implement failover for a web service client for times when the server hosting the web service is being restarted.  I attempted to implement the code below, which worked pretty well, but with two problems:

1. The first time "failure" occurred, the client would switch to the next alternate address but would not actually complete the web service call.
2. When the primary server came back up, the client would not switch back to using that server.  Instead it would continue using whichever server it was currently using.

Here's the code:

```
<jaxws:client id="someService"
        serviceClass="com.foo.bar.webservice.service.SomeService"
        address="https://myserver.server.net/webservices/cxf/SomeService" 
        username="myuser"
        password="mypassword">

    <jaxws:features>
        <clustering:failover>
            <clustering:strategy>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.clustering.SequentialStrategy">
                    <property name="alternateAddresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>otherserver/webservices/cxf/SomeService</value>
                            <value>thirdserver/webservices/cxf/SomeService</value>
                        </list>
                     </property>
                </bean>
            </clustering:strategy>
        </clustering:failover>
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:client>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a web server like Apache httpd to load balance between nodes of an application server cluster. Then clustering and fail over is not something your application has to manage.

Comment: While I would agree that failover through load balancing is probably the cleanest and easiest solution, it won't quite work for me.  This service call is triggered by the receiving of a JMS message, and I can't afford to drop a message even if all potential nodes are unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try an alternative CXF failover feature which has what you need (ability to failback)
https://github.com/jaceko/cxf-circuit-switcher

Comment: On paper this is exactly what I am asking for.  I've already implemented a custom/manual solution, but I'll see if at some point I can go back and try this out.